# Let's rename [google-plus-hangouts] to [google-hangouts]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

In Google's ongoing effort to divorce functionality from Google+, the "Plus" part of the name for Google Hangouts was dropped several months ago. As you can see from the [official page](https://hangouts.google.com/), the name of the product/service is simply "Google Hangouts". The [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk) is simply named "Hangouts" (but they often drop the "Google" from their smartphone app names).

I cannot create a [google-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) (likely because of the existence of [google-hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangout)) so we'll need a Moderator's help here.

- Please create a tag: [google-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts).
- Make [google-plus-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts) a synonym.
- Change [google-hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangout) and [hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hangout) to be synonyms of [google-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts). (They are currently synonyms of [google-plus-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts).)

Comment: Are there any other `google-plus-*` tags that need to go as well?

Comment: @ChrisF: I don't know, but I'll take a look. [tag:google-hangouts-onair] seems to be going/have gone away, but that'll disappear by normal attrition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do the rename you have to merge the tags which seems to have had the side effect of merging [hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hangout) and [google-hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangout) into [google-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) as well.

The cache takes a little while to catch up but if you spot any weirdness after a couple of days let us know.